# "going through someone's car"

Tags: idioms, semantics

I encountered the following sentence:

> He and two friends were going through someone's car and someone caught them and shot at them, killing my student.

What does "go through someone's car" mean?

Comment: [Go through](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go-through?q=go+through) means "Search through or examine methodically:
she started to go through the bundle of letters"

Comment: This would be a fairly normal way to describe someone searching through a car, presumably for things to steal.  The police have informed us that there were people doing this to cars on our block two nights ago.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Sometimes – and especially in contexts like this – there's some "slangy", yet oft-used, idioms that are not to be found from normal dictionaries. That's why I prefer to ask here, instead of choosing the definition from dictionary that seems to be the "least off" of many. More than once I've got some insight that wasn't evident by just looking it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Going through" something (in this context) generally refers to searching through someone's belongings looking for something of value. It's more often used in the context of spaces or objects used to store things - for instance: "going through her purse" or "going through his filing cabinet".

In this example, the usage strikes me as being somewhat odd, because a car is principally a mode of transportation. However, a car does have glove compartments and other areas that money and other valuables may be stored. So you can infer that "going through someone's car" is referring to the act of searching through those storage areas inside the car (possibly after having forced an unlawful entry into the vehicle) to locate valuables (presumably with the intent of stealing them).

Comment: Not "odd" at all.  Several years ago someone "went through" my Honda Odyssey and stole a CD player from the dash and some cash in the glove compartment.  (They overlooked, however, about a thousand dollars worth of tools in the back.)